# How to find the history of a deleted answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, edit-history

> I'd like to know how can one find the history of a deleted answer?

In particular, of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1680571/121097).

Comment: @zyx Thanks. This is the link I was looking for, but how did you find it? Is there something near the answer which I've missed, or simply use the link you mentioned by introducing the appropriate number (that is, the number of the answer we are looking for to see its edit history)?

Comment: @user26857: It's just there, in the answer, just like here you have "edited 20 minutes ago" (at time of posting this comment).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh well, I don't know how I've miss it! Thanks again!

Comment: You can also find the post number by clicking "share" and copying the first number appearing in the link (the second is your user number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question was edited, there's a link to the revision history, just like there will be with undeleted answers. In this case, https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1680571/revisions

And if it wasn't edited, then using `https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/<answer number here>/revisions` will work just fine.

You can also access the timeline by replacing `revisions` by `timeline`. So in your case, https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1680571/timeline will work.

Comment: Of course, all of that will be visible only for [users who can view deleted questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (10k+ and diamonds).

Comment: @Martin: I thought about making that comment, but I figured it goes without saying... I guess it goes with saying, now. :-)

Comment: Are revisions and timeline visible to author of the answer (when under 10k)?  @MartinSleziak

Comment: @zyx I guess so. (It seems logical, since they see can see the question.)

Comment: @zyx since it is not clear to me if 'deleted' is implicit in your query a supplement:  owner can see it for their deleted posts as Martin said; for not deleted post, they are accessible to  everybody.